# Two SSID's, same name, different keys. Will the stronger signal disconnect the other one's clients?

Tags: wireless-networking

I’m having the following problem.

- I live in an apartment and my neighbor insists in using another neighbor’s WPA2-secured network of which he has the key.
- Doing this, he has to stay in the public hallway, otherwise the connection gets out of range.
- This is annoying me, he’s invading my privacy.

If I set up an old but powerful router with the same SSID as my neighbor's, also WPA2 encrypted, but with a different key (I don’t know my neighbor's key), will this prevent the guy in the hallway from connecting?

To his devices my signal will be significantly stronger than my neighbor’s (the owner of the WiFi network) who lives on another floor, and neither Windows, nor Android list the different networks with the same SSID, instead they see them as one and the same.

Comment: It'd certainly cause problems, possibly for your somewhat innocent neighbour whose WiFi it is. Would it not be easier just to voice your concern with them as their WiFi is being leeched?

Comment: So it annoys you, get over it.

Comment: It makes you just as bad as him, but yes - it will work. Make sure it is the same channel. 

Then rat him out.

Comment: My neighbor is aware of the problem, but is unable to do something about it, because her daughter just spreads any new key to everybody, So I have to do something to get rid of the guy leaning against the wall at my door all day, invading my privacy, listening to anything I say and looking through my windows.

Comment: If the neighbour running the AP also sees this as a problem, you could help her configuring the AP that it only allows certain MACs. This would kick him out, as long as he does not start faking mac adresses.

You could also solve this the nice way by giving him access to your own, strong AP (with decent limitations), which reaches into his flat.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably cause problems for the hallway-standing neighbor, but you can't rule out the possibility that it could cause problems for the network-owning neighbor.

If you're intent on unneighborly passive aggression, consider forging deauths from the real network's BSSID to the hallway-standing neighbor's wireless MAC address.

Comment: I know how to do it, but I'm not sure whether it's legal.

Answer (score 0):

The SSID is not a problem when you use a different channel.
The SSID is a different problem that is explained later.
Most WLANs are on channel one, six, or eleven by default.
In an apartment building, a standard procedure in setting up a WLAN router is to scan the channels, see who is using what, and then select an unused channel that is as far away as possible from the heavy usage as possible. (Usually channel 3). You will notice that using an unused channel also provides better speeds because there are no "collisions". Now to the SSID:: Never use a common SSID that contains the name or model of the WLAN router. Making this error makes it easier for hackers to break in because they can quickly look up the known weaknesses of a specific model on the internet.

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question? They asked if a duplicate SSID from a different router, and a different key would prevent his neighbor from connecting to the weaker signal. The channel it is on makes no difference in this situation.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.